# Angular 7 multiply a value returned from web api by a number

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular7

I am very new to Angular...

I have a html5 meter and I want to set the low variable to a value returned from a web api by 0.25.

I have the following from within my meter:

```
low="{{com.highlimit | number : '1.0-0'} * 0.25}"
```

where {{com.highlimit}} equals 100.

This doesnt appear to work as my meter doesnt change color.  If I amend the above to `low="25"` then it works as expected.

I presume it is treating `* 0.25` as a string?

My question is how do I use math in this use case?

Comment: That's not valid template syntax. You always open a template with `{{` and close it with `}}`. Try `low="{{ (com.highlimit | number : '1.0-0') * 0.25 }}"`.

Comment: looks good, if you submit it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that

```
"{{com.highlimit | number : '1.0-0'} * 0.25}"
```

is not a valid [string interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions) in Angular's template syntax.

Everything between `{{` and `}}` is evaluated as an expression and everything around it is just a literal string. But it there have to be *two* opening and closing curly braces.

Try this instead:

```
low="{{ (com.highlimit | number : '1.0-0') * 0.25 }}"
```

The parentheses are necessary unfortunately.